# How can the current number of i be accessed in a for of loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given a for of loop the value of the assigned the variable(`i` for this example) is equal to what `array[i]` would equal if it was a normal for loop. How can the index of the array the that `i` is currently on be accessed.

What I want

```
let array = ["one", "two", "three"];

for (let i of array) {
  console.log(i);// normally logs cycle one : "one", cycle two : "two", cycle three : "three".
  console.log(/*what equals the current index*/);// what I want to log cycle one : 1, cycle two : 2, cycle three : 3. 
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about javascript, but in other languages, you would loop over the length of the array, then over the array itself.

Comment: `let array = ["one", "two", "three"];
let index=0;
for (let i of array) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(index++)
}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

nothing simple ... if you want "simple access" to both the item and the index in a loop over an array, use `forEach` e.g.

```
array.forEach(function(item, index) { 
... 
});
```

or as T.J. Crowder pointer out (and I missed the ES6 tag)

```
array.forEach((item, index) => { 
    ... 
});
```

like many programming languages, javascript has multiple ways to do similar things, the skill is in choosing the right tool for the job

Comment: This seems to be the best solution for the described problem.

Comment: In ES6, there's actually no reason to use `forEach` any more.

Comment: I'm intrigued - what would you use instead ... hmmm ... just saw the `for/of` with `.entries` answer ...

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) function. It will return a index/value pair for each entry in the array like:

```
[0, "one"]
[1, "two"]
[2, "three"]
```

Use this in tandem with [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) to resolve each entry to the appropriate variable name:

```
const arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
for(const [index, value] of arr.entries()) {
  console.log(index, value);
}
```

[Babel REPL Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%22one%22%2C%20%22two%22%2C%20%22three%22%5D%0Afor(const%20%5Bkey%2C%20value%5D%20of%20arr.entries())%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(key%2C%20value)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: I like your answer, and it is technically correct, but it would seem more intuitive to me to use `index` instead of `key`.

Comment: @AndrewWillems Interesting point, I had actually assumed (incorrectly) that `entries()` would also iterate any properties set on the Array (i.e. `arr.one = "1"`) but that isn't actually the case, so you're right it should be `[index, value]`

Comment: For the record, `key` _is_ technically correct even so far as to be the correct/only keyword to use to access just those values. e.g. `for (let i of arr.keys()) {console.log(i);}` produces "0, 1, 2". But, just to make the point again slightly differently, while JavaScript arrays _do_ have a form of keys (with the caveat you point out) they are sequential numeric keys and we typically think of those as `index`es (or indices, or whatever spelling you want). So, with respect to code readability, I think your re-edit of your answer to use `index` instead of `key` is still best.

Comment: This should be the correct answer to the question IMHO.

Comment: For Typescript validity, add `Array.from()` around `arr.entries()`: `Array.from(arr.entries())` to prevent TS2488.

Comment: And how does `Array.entries()` perform compared to a regular for-loop? What temporary objects are allocated?

Answer (score 5):

You mean this?

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(i); // Logs the current index number;
  console.log(array[i]); // Logs the index matching in the array;
}
```

Also a good [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538944/how-can-the-current-number-of-i-be-accessed-in-a-for-of-loop/33539038#comment54872336_33539038) from [Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702797/kaiido) was that you can use this to get the value from the array directly as a variable.

```
for (var ind = 0, i=array[ind]; ind < array.length; i=array[++ind]) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(ind);
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to have easy access to the idem in the array with just `i` without having to use `array[i]`.

Comment: @user5448026, Your question was hard to understand :p, but why not use `array[i]`? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: What is _not_ easy about `array[i]`?

Comment: @Kaiido: Actually that doesn't work as you don't update `i` in every iteration.

Comment: @Bergi oups, you're right. It should have been `for (var ind = 0,i=array[ind] ; ind < array.length; i=array[++ind]) { 
console.log(i);
console.log(ind);
}` but I personaly always prefer the `arr[x]` notation

Comment: @Thaillie, I'm not sure it worth more than a comment, writing twice `i=array[ind]` and `i=array[++ind]` instead of one `let i = array[i]` in the loop doesn't seem so clever to me :-)

Comment: @Kaiido, just edit the answer to make something more usefull of it :p, it shouldn't be the accepted answer anyway because I [think](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33539012/4050842) this one is better :p

Comment: The answer by @jaromanda-x is much better than this: more readable, declarative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) function to get an iterator that includes the indices.

```
for (let [index, value] of [1, 2, 3].entries())
  console.log(index + ':' + value);
```

or, if you dont like the `let [,]` notation:

```
for (let entry of [1, 2, 3].entries())
  console.log(entry[0]+ ':' + entry[1]);
```

But what about other array-likes? Well, you could easily just take care of it yourself, really

```
let index = 0;
for (let ch of 'abcd') {
  ++index;
  //your code
}
```

Or, you can pretty easily [patch in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) your own implementation

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'indexerator', {get:function() {
    var elements = this[Symbol.iterator]();
    var index = 0;
    var output;

    return {
        [Symbol.iterator] : function() { return this; },
        next : function() {
            if (!(output = elements.next()).done)
                output.value = [index++, output.value];
            return output;
        }
    };
}});

/*other code*/

for (let [index, ch] of 'abcd'.indexerator)
  console.log(index + ':' + ch);
```

<sub>[demonstrations](http://codepen.io/Hashbrown/pen/grvYkG)</sub>

Comment: For a string, you can just include `.split('')` to convert the string to an array of characters and then proceed as usual, i.e. `for (let [index, ch] of 'abcd'.split('').entries()) {...}`.

Comment: Cool. It was just an easily understood example, your solution will work for strings but wont help you if you needed to patch, say a `NodeList` on slightly older webkit browsers (which, for some reason, support iterators but NodeList wasn't yet made to be one itself). To have to write that long expression each time you wanted to do something like that in a project would be unwieldy, in which case you'd probably end up turning it into a function, making it no less complicated than the solution here anyway (`.indexerator`, the patching function is just defined once hidden in a utility somewhere).

Comment: @AndrewWillems If the string isn't converting to an array a waste of memory and can cause problems? Better to add your own index.

Answer (score 1):

use `indexOf` to get the index back

```
let array = ["one", "two", "three"];

for (let i of array) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(array.indexOf(i));
}
```

**NOTE:** will only work for a array with no duplicates.

Comment: what about `let array = ["one", "two", "three", "one"];`

Comment: true, though the question did not mention duplicates. updated my answer.

Comment: Right but this will return the first index of the value in the array, which is not the same as "the actual index of the array being accessed"

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"];

for (i = 0, item; item=array[i]; i++) {
  console.log(i); // Logs the current index number;
  console.log(item); // Logs the current item in the array;
}
```